# Can I connect to my Mac via thin client?

Tags: macos, remote-desktop

I want a remote access to my Mac. I'm looking for a hardware solution - a thin client (zero client), PCoIP client - a hardware client, which can connects my Monitor/Keyboard/Mouse over network to my Mac.
Does such hardware exists?

Comment: So basically, thin clients that speak VNC is what you seek? There are tons of small computers (RaspberryPi, etc) that run unix and work well for this, but it will be interesting if there are others people consider more thin on the client side.

Comment: Need a high speed client, those linux-boxes too weak to display films, games graphics.

Comment: Will you have enough network bandwidth available? I suspect the network will be your main limiting factor. What are you looking to set up? A home games/entertainment system or a remote work/office environment, or something else entirely?

Comment: Please describe what you want to do so we can help you find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

TeamViewer for your iPad/iPhone?

Setup TeamViewer to run on startup and you should be good to go.

Or are you looking for your local machine to login to your Mac and run the Mac as if booting up?

Comment: Still looking for the latter — booting my thin client (e.g. an old MacBook Air) directly into session with my server (a high-spec Mac mini), without running a whole OS locally on the client. Anyone figure this out since 2013.